# Is there a way to capture a user command to bash which was not found and do something with it?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Suppose I type saklfjsklj in bash, I get:

```
bash: saklfjsklj: command not found
```

Is there a way to intercept that and execute a script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bash has a `command_not_found_handle` callback: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution

There's info at [this answer on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73262/how-do-i-teach-bash-in-ubuntu-some-curse-words/73282#73282) about messing with the default.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function named `command_not_found_handle`. The command and arguments will be passed as arguments to the function.

```
$ command_not_found_handle() { echo "$@"'!'; }
$ zounds
zounds!
```

Answer (score 1):

From the bash man page,

*If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function named command_not_found_handle.  If that function exists, it is invoked with the original command and the original command's arguments as its arguments, and the function's exit status becomes the exit status of the shell.  If that function is not defined, the  shell  prints  an  error message  and returns an exit status of 127.*

I also found this article on the subject,

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-command-not-found